# How can I convert a GML with multiple layers to a GeoJSON and store layer name in FeatureType property?

Tags: python, geojson, convert, ogr2ogr, gml

I have a GML file that has multiple layers and I want to convert it to GeoJSON. Apparently, GeoJSON cannot handle multiple layers explicitly. Thus, I want to store the layer name in a property called featuretype.

I could not find any ogr2ogr command that can do it.
I saw that in GDAl 3.8, there is a new driver called JSONFG
OGC Features and Geometries JSON.

https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/jsonfg.html#vector-jsonfg

However, the latest verison of GDAL I was able to download is 3.7.1

What kind of solution do I have meanwhile the new driver is out? I look for a command or even a python script that can do the job.

the sample of input GML:

```
    <member>
        <S123:RadioServiceArea gml:id="RDOSVC">
            <categoryOfBroadcastCommunication>commercial</categoryOfBroadcastCommunication>
            <radiocommunications>
                <categoryOfRadioMethods>Medium Frequency (MF) voice traffic</categoryOfRadioMethods>
                <signalFrequency>720</signalFrequency>
                <transmissionContent>Gale warning, High sea forecast, weather reports from coast stations and the coastal forecast.</transmissionContent>
            </radiocommunications>
            <serviceProvider xlink:href="#RDOSTA01" xlink:arcrole="http://www.iho.int/s123/gml/1.0/roles/serviceProvider"/>
            <geometry>
                <S100:surfaceProperty>
                    <S100:Surface gml:id="RDOSVC.S">
                        <gml:patches>
                            <gml:PolygonPatch>
                                <gml:exterior>
                                    <gml:LinearRing>
                                        <gml:posList>60.7667 -32.6333 60.7667 -32.3167 61.3333 -32.3167 61.3333 -32.6333 60.7667 -32.6333</gml:posList>
                                    </gml:LinearRing>
                                </gml:exterior>
                            </gml:PolygonPatch>
                        </gml:patches>
                    </S100:Surface>
                </S100:surfaceProperty>
            </geometry>
        </S123:RadioServiceArea>
    </member>
```

the wanted GeoJSON:

```
{"type":"Feature","id":"7196:17073:1","properties":{"featureType":"RadioServiceArea","categoryOfBroadcastCommunication":  ["3","3"],"featureName":  [{"displayName":  ["1","1"],"name":  ["Digby Island RT HF","Digby Island RT HF"]},{"displayName":  ["1","1"],"name":  ["Digby Island RT HF","Digby Island RT HF"]}],"radiocommunications":  [{"categoryOfRadioMethods":  ["3","3"]},{"categoryOfRadioMethods":  ["3","3"]}]},"geometry": {"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[-141.0214189,57.468104],[-141.0214189,57.468104],[-140.1532199,57.675539],[-138.6325353,58.0352508],[-137.1118508,58.3913663],[-135.5911663,58.7439081],[-134.0704817,59.0928992],[-141.6739044,57.3122085],[-141.0214189,57.468104],[-141.0214189,57.468104]]]}},
{"type":"Feature","id":"7196:17072:1","properties":{"featureType":"RadioServiceArea","categoryOfBroadcastCommunication":  ["3","3"],"featureName":  [{"name":  ["AMVER","AMVER"]},{"name":  ["AMVER","AMVER"]}],"radiocommunications":  [{"transmissionContent":  ["AMVER report reception/forwarding services are available.","AMVER report reception/forwarding services are available."]},{"transmissionContent":  ["AMVER report reception/forwarding services are available.","AMVER report reception/forwarding services are available."]}]},"geometry": {"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[-141.0214189,57.468104],[-141.0214189,57.468104],[-140.1532199,57.675539],[-138.6325353,58.0352508],[-137.1118508,58.3913663],[-143.3139868,56.9161366],[-143.194589,56.9452372],[-141.6739044,57.3122085],[-141.0214189,57.468104],[-141.0214189,57.468104]]]}},
```

Comment: Isn't this the same question that you asked already https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/464435/error-in-converting-a-gml-with-multiple-layers-to-geojson-error-1-layer-2-d?

Comment: It is the same problem, but in that question I was asking how to fix that bug. Now, I am asking what is the best way to do this conversion.

Comment: It is possible to edit a question.